# Is there a way to perform an IF() evaluation and execute a stored procedure all on one line?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to write this so it can be all on one line of code?

```
IF (ISNULL(@param1,'1') = '1' AND ISNULL(@param2,'') = '') 
   exec sp_CheckNill @param2, '@param2 cannot be NULL if @param1 is NOT NULL'
```

For the inevitable "why?" questions:  besides being more compact, if I'm doing lots of these in a row, readability is far better as the individual differences between each line are for more distinct.

EDIT:

I'm an idiot.  All on one line does work:

```
IF (ISNULL(@param1,'1') = '1' AND ISNULL(@param2,'') = '') exec sp_CheckNill @param2, '@param2 cannot be NULL if @param1 is NOT NULL'
```

I'd delete the question, except @James below posted an informative related answer.

Comment: If readability is your *only* concern, have you considered just indenting the second line way past the length of the first line? It would make it a zig-zag pattern to read but at least the IF's and the EXEC's would be neatly lined up and not "mixed".

Comment: Also, what happens if you actually do write it all on one line?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why can't you just have it on one line.... Just move it onto the other line.

Comment: This works:    IF 1=1 PRINT 'hi'     So I don't see why your code wouldn't.   Do you get an error?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to have the right semantics anyway according to the message you pass to the proc. Why aren't you just testing `@param1 is not null and @param2 is null`?

Comment: Sorry guys, boneheaded question, I edited it to reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can it be done, yes.  You must be very careful, though, because the type of whitespace (returns vs. spaces) doesn't affect SQL (or most programming languages).  By putting the body of an `IF` statement on the same line, you may trick your later self or others into thinking that the whitespace actually makes a difference (even if you consciously know that it doesn't).

Here are some examples:

```
IF @condition=1 EXEC func1 EXEC func2
```

will ALWAYS execute `func2`, even though from the formatting it appears to be part of the `IF`.

`ELSE` clauses add to the confusion:

```
IF @condition1=1
    IF @condition2=1 EXEC func1
ELSE EXEC func2
```

In this case, `func2` will not execute if @contition1 is zero. It will only execute if @condition1 is 1 and @condition2 is not 1 because the `ELSE` is tied to the second `IF`, not the first, despite the way the formatting makes it look.

Due to these issues, many companies have strict coding guidelines that forbid the use of `IF`s without explicit `BEGIN` and `END` statements (or braces in the case of many other programming languages), which makes all such statements clear.  You will have to decide for yourself how to avoid this type of confusion.

Comment: This isn't as funny as my answer.

Comment: Are you sure about the `func3` example? I think func3 is unrealted to `condition1`, only related to `condition2`. (Unless you did it on purpose, to show that it is indeed confusing. Hats off for that ;)

Comment: @ypercube: thanks, I indeed confused myself--a great unintended illustration of the problem.  Corrected!

Answer (score 4):

Works fine. Really, sometimes you just need to try it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_CheckNill
(
    @p0 varchar(30)
,   @p1 varchar(30)
)
as
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    PRINT 'This works';
END
GO
DECLARE
    @param1 char(1)
,   @param2 varchar(30);

IF (ISNULL(@param1,'1') = '1' AND ISNULL(@param2,'') = '') 
   exec sp_CheckNill @param2, '@param2 cannot be NULL if @param1 is NOT NULL';

IF (ISNULL(@param1,'1') = '1' AND ISNULL(@param2,'') = '') EXEC sp_CheckNill @param2, '@param2 cannot be NULL if @param1 is NOT NULL';
```

Results

```
This works
This works
```

[image]

Comment: How did you make and post that gif?

Comment: @tbone LICECap  - http://www.cockos.com/licecap/